# HTML parser - How to copy/export a text code from some 500 html pages to another 500 pages with the same link address

Tags: python, php, html, bash, powershell

I want to copy/export a different text code from some 500 html pages to another 500 pages with the same link address, but with different content.

For example, the lines below from the `page-1.html` must be exported / copied to another folder, also in a file with the same name `page-1.html`. And the same to the other thousands of pages.

In fact, I must export/copy everything before `<body>` from `file-1.html (Folder-1)` to `file-1.html (Folder-2)`. Remember that the files content is different, the only connection id the same name.

```
<!-- START HERE --> 
 
<?php
    // Use API site scope.
    define('RW_SDK__API_SCOPE', 'site');
        
    $item_id = 1; // Replace that with your rating id.
    
    $rating_class = 'page';  
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>My page 1</title>
<link rel="icon" href="https://my-website.com/love.ico" sizes="192x192" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="main" href="cars.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://my-website/my-page-1.html" />
<meta name="resource-type" content="document"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="distribution" content="global"/>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public"/>
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Latest News" href="https://feeds.feedburner.com/my-website"/>
<meta name="description" content="My content"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="my, content"/>
<meta name="Robots" content="index,follow"/>
<meta name="googlebot" content="index,follow"/>
<meta name="expire" content="never"/>
<meta name="revisit-after" content="10 days"/>
<link rel="sitemap" type="application/rss+xml" href="rss.xml" /> 
<link rel="image_src" type="image/jpeg" href="https://my-website.com/icon-facebook.jpg" style="display:none"/>    
<meta itemprop="image" content="https://my-website.com/icon-facebook.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://my-website.com/icon-facebook.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:type"  content="article" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="721561911"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="716441"/>
<meta name="yandex-verification" content="6b7169b283c6c9cc" />
<meta property="og:title" content="My page 1" />

<!-- END HERE --> 

</head>
<body>
...other tags...
```

You can see here exactly what I want to do

[image]

and here:

[image]

Comment: hi. This question seems little bit abstact to me. But it's not a matter of copying the text. It's a matter how the website is built, with what technology and how do you handle errors in it. Please be more specific.

Comment: I don't understand what you need to do. Maybe if you showed a simplfied example of current state and new state?

Comment: The entire website is write in html, the new template also in html, except the css is very different. So first, I must copy those meta tags to each pages of my new template. For SEO. Cannot copy one by one each 500 html pages, take a lot of time.

Comment: Is CSS the only difference? Anyway, feels like a job for an HTML parser.

Comment: yes, HTML parser, exactly. But how can I do this ?

Comment: hello, please see the update of the post. I make a print screen to see more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably other ways to do this that may be more optimal, but below is a variation of some PowerShell logic that appears to do the trick.

This will take care of updating the content part in the destination files as described from the source file contents which have matching file names.

## PowerShell

```
$src = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Folder1" -Filter "*.html";
$destFld = "C:\Folder2";

$src | % { Process {
 
    If ( Test-Path "$destFld\$($_.Name)" ) { 

        Clear-Variable -Name ("a","b","y","z");
        $z = Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw;
        $y = "$((($z -split "</head>")[0]).Trim())`r`n";
        $a = Get-Content "$destFld\$($_.Name)" -Raw;
        $b = (($a -split "</head>")[1]).Trim();
        $y | Out-File "$destFld\$($_.Name)";
        "</head>" | Out-File "$destFld\$($_.Name)" -Append;
        $b | Out-File "$destFld\$($_.Name)" -Append;

        }
}};
```

#### Before and After Result Examples

**File-1.html (used for update content)**

```
<!-- START HERE --> 
 
<?php
    // Use API site scope.
    define('RW_SDK__API_SCOPE', 'site');
        
    $item_id = 1; // Replace that with your rating id.
    
    $rating_class = 'page';  
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>My page 1</title>
<link rel="icon" href="https://my-website.com/love.ico" sizes="192x192" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="main" href="cars.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://my-website/my-page-1.html" />
<meta name="resource-type" content="document"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="distribution" content="global"/>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public"/>
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Latest News" href="https://feeds.feedburner.com/my-website"/>
<meta name="description" content="My content"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="my, content"/>
<meta name="Robots" content="index,follow"/>
<meta name="googlebot" content="index,follow"/>
<meta name="expire" content="never"/>
<meta name="revisit-after" content="10 days"/>
<link rel="sitemap" type="application/rss+xml" href="rss.xml" /> 
<link rel="image_src" type="image/jpeg" href="https://my-website.com/icon-facebook.jpg" style="display:none"/>    
<meta itemprop="image" content="https://my-website.com/icon-facebook.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://my-website.com/icon-facebook.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:type"  content="article" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="721561911"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="716441"/>
<meta name="yandex-verification" content="6b7169b283c6c9cc" />
<meta property="og:title" content="My page 1" />

<!-- END HERE --> 

</head>
<body>
...other tags...
```

**File-2.html (before update)**

```
<!-- START HERE --> 
 
<?php
    // Use API site scope.
    define('RW_SDK__API_SCOPE', 'site');
        
    $item_id = 1; // Replace that with your rating id.
    
    $rating_class = 'page';  
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>My page 1</title>
<link rel="icon" href="https://my-website.com/hate.ico" sizes="192x192" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="main" href="bars.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://my-website/my-page-2.html" />
<meta name="resource-type" content="document"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="distribution" content="global"/>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public"/>
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Latest News" href="https://feeds.fastlearner.com/my-mess"/>
<meta name="description" content="My content"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="no, content"/>
<meta name="Robots" content="index,follow"/>
<meta name="googlebot" content="index,follow"/>
<meta name="expire" content="always"/>
<meta name="revisit-after" content="2 days"/>
<link rel="sitemap" type="application/rss+xml" href="rss.xml" /> 
<link rel="image_src" type="image/jpeg" href="https://my-website.com/icon-myspace.jpg" style="display:none"/>    
<meta itemprop="image" content="https://my-website.com/icon-myspace.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://my-website.com/icon-myspace.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:type"  content="article" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="721561022"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="716552"/>
<meta name="yandex-verification" content="6b7169b283c6c8dd" />
<meta property="og:title" content="My page 1" />

<!-- END HERE --> 

</head>
<body>
...other tags 2...
```

**File-2.html (after update)**

```
<?php
    // Use API site scope.
    define('RW_SDK__API_SCOPE', 'site');
        
    $item_id = 1; // Replace that with your rating id.
    
    $rating_class = 'page';  
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>My page 1</title>
<link rel="icon" href="https://my-website.com/love.ico" sizes="192x192" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="main" href="cars.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://my-website/my-page-1.html" />
<meta name="resource-type" content="document"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="distribution" content="global"/>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public"/>
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Latest News" href="https://feeds.feedburner.com/my-website"/>
<meta name="description" content="My content"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="my, content"/>
<meta name="Robots" content="index,follow"/>
<meta name="googlebot" content="index,follow"/>
<meta name="expire" content="never"/>
<meta name="revisit-after" content="10 days"/>
<link rel="sitemap" type="application/rss+xml" href="rss.xml" /> 
<link rel="image_src" type="image/jpeg" href="https://my-website.com/icon-facebook.jpg" style="display:none"/>    
<meta itemprop="image" content="https://my-website.com/icon-facebook.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://my-website.com/icon-facebook.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:type"  content="article" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="721561911"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="716441"/>
<meta name="yandex-verification" content="6b7169b283c6c9cc" />
<meta property="og:title" content="My page 1" />

<!-- END HERE -->

</head>
<body>
...other tags 2...
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [If()](https://ss64.com/ps/if.html)
- [Split()](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html)
- [Trim()](https://ss64.com/ps/trim.html)
- [Clear-Variable](https://ss64.com/ps/clear-variable.html)
- [Get-Content](https://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html)
- [Out-File](https://ss64.com/ps/out-file.html)
- [About Special Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7.1)

  > a. **`n** :   New line
  >
  > b. **`r** :   Carriage return
  >
  > Where b. and a. : `CRLF` EOL
- [How-to: Change the line endings of a text file](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-set-eol.html)

Comment: @JustMe .... Be sure to test this on a small sample set of files before you run it on your production files just in case. Also, be sure to have a backup of the production files too regardless before you run.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution in **PowerShell**, easy to understand, is to use REGEX: `\A(.*)[\s\S]+(<body>)` (This regex selects/copy everything from beginning of file to `<body>`, including `<body>`.

```
$sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem 'c:\Folder1'  
$destinationFolder = 'c:\Folder2'

foreach ($file in $sourceFiles) {

$sourceContent = Get-Content $file.FullName -Raw
$contentToInsert = [regex]::match($sourceContent,"\A(.*)[\s\S]+(<body>)").value
$destinationContent = Get-Content $destinationFolder\$($file.Name) -Raw
$destinationContent = $destinationContent -replace '\A(.*)[\s\S]+(<body>)',$contentToInsert

Set-Content -Path $destinationFolder\$($file.Name) -Value $destinationContent -Encoding UTF8

} #end foreach file
```

Answer (score -1):

That's why you should use a template engine before working on those 500 html pages. All the headers logic in one single file and then the specifics on other places.

About the html parser. You can use any language to parse those 500 html pages and then create the others. For example, there is [this post](https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/web-scraping-ruby/) where the author explains how to parse a website and export it to other formats. You can try to export to HTML.

Comment: Thanks for provide a reason about the -1. You could have avoided comparing my solution to the others so explicitly tho. "As you can see, [...]" that was unnecessary and condescending.